# Recently used files not working for screenshots created with ALT - PRINT

Tags: gimp, screenshot

I create a screentshot with ALT - PRINT.

The file gets created in my ~/Bilder (German for Images) directory.

But if I open Gimp and then choose "open" then "Recently files", I don't see the screenshot I took a minute ago.

How to make the screenshot available in the recently use files?

I mean "recently used files" from this dialog:

[image: recently-used-files--gimp]

"Zuletzt ..." is German for "Recently used"

Comment: I think that "Recent Files" in Gimp are files that you recently have opened in Gimp, not files that you recently created in other applications. Most applications work this way.

Comment: It works for me.

Comment: @SorenA No, that is definitely not the case. "Open / Recently used" shows all image files that have been recently used, whether or not opened by Gimp. At least that is how it works on my system.

Comment: @Jos I updated the question and added a screenshot.

Comment: Do you have your "file history" turned off? See [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/privacy-history-recent-off.html.en).

Comment: A limitation, I guess. Only files accessed using graphical applications are registered, not files created from a command (which is launched through the shortcut key). Open the file once in Gimp or a viewer, and it will make it into the list.

Comment: @vanadium But why does it work on my system then? (21.10, Gimp 2.10.24)

Comment: Doe not work for me on 21.10, however it is a flatpak version of Gimp. But the file appears in eog indeed. Perhaps this is a snap version of Gimp? OP, plese clarify.

Comment: It also works for me: Ubuntu 21.10, normal (`apt`) installation of Gimp 2.10.24.

Answer (score 0):

First, there are two distinct "Recent files" in Gimp:

- Those in `File ➤ Open recent` (Gimp edit history)
- Those in the `Recently used` tab in the file selection dialog from `File ➤ Open...` which are shared between applications. For instance, a file freshly downloaded with Firefox will appear here in Gimp, and conversely you can export a file in Gimp, and then immediately upload it in Firefox, where it will appear at the top of the "Recent files".

This is all about the second ones.

The `Recently used` files in Gimp come from the file `.local/share/recently-used.xbel`. This file is normally shared among applications.

But in some packagings (flatpak, at least, IIRC) Gimp is "sandboxed" and made to see a virtual file system where directories can be different from those of the rest of the OS, and this makes it use its own copy of `.local/share/recently-used.xbel` that defeats its purpose.

I no longer use the Gimp flatpak, but at the time I managed to fix the problem by replacing the `.local/share/`in the flatpak by a soft link to the real `.local/share/`. You can't link `recently-used.xbel` directly because to update it applications (including Gimp) erase it and recreate it and this replaces the soft link by a real file. Linking the parent directory works because the applications do not remove/replace the directory so the link remains. As far as I could tell this has no ill effects (`recently-used.xbel` appears to be the only file that Gimp uses in it).

Another side-effect of sandboxing was that  Gimp had its own private `/tmp` so you couldn't share files with other apps that uses `/tmp` for this (in my case, the Spectacle screen capture app). But this could have been fixed.